# What is context in WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I come across the term "context" allot when researching asynchronous programming but I could never understand the true meaning and what it represents. Why do I need it and what it represents?

I vaguely understand the term "context", I say vaguely because when it comes to `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` I am not sure when to use it? or why am using it?

I have read Stephen Cleary's blogs several times and still struggle to understand `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` Is there an example when to and when not to use it?

Am I right to say if I have two async methods and the second async operation relies on the first one I should not use `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);`?

```
public async static Task TestAsync()
{
    // Contains data that `GetDataFromLinkUsingHttpClient()` needs.
    var link = await GetLinkFromApiUsingHttpClient();

    // The method use `GetLinkFromApiUsingHttpClient()` data.
    await GetDataFromLinkUsingHttpClient(link);
}
```

Comment: You are probably interested in `ExecutionContext` which captures `SynchronizationContext` and some other Contexts.  Here is some [info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/)

Comment: You would use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to indicate that the code *after* the `await` does not rely on being in the same context as the code *before* it.  By default, `await` assumes that it *does*, which is safe, but has a slight performance impact. `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't imply that the 2 `await` operations are dependent on each other, having 2 separate `await` calls does that no matter how it is configured.

Comment: When to use it? When you are writing a library. Why? Because when you don't use configure await and someone wants to execute this method synchronously in asp.net app they will probably do: `var result = GetDataFromLinkUsingHttpClient(link).Result`, which will deadlock the application. This is because `ConfigureAwait` will keep running code after `await` on the same thread `await` executed on, but this is well covered by many blog posts that you can look for.

Comment: Just the clarity I was looking for thanks